# Kostka number under dominance relation

Tags: combinatorics, representation-theory

The Kostka number is defined as the number $K_{\lambda\mu}$ of semistandard Young tableaux, i.e, strictly increasing column, (nonstrictly) increasing column of the shape $\lambda$ and content $\mu$. I have seen a statement that $\lambda\unrhd\mu$ then $K_{\lambda\mu}>0$. But for $\lambda=(4,3,3)$ and $\mu=(4,2,4)$. It seems does not work:

1 1 1 1

2 2 3

3 3 3 not strictly increasing here..

Answer (score 2):

You're getting confused by the ordering of $\mu$. It's true that $K_{\lambda\mu} = K_{\lambda\nu}$ whenever $\mu$ and $\nu$ are rearrangements of each other. For that reason, one very often assumes $\mu$ is a partition to begin with, i.e. $\mu$ is weakly decreasing. This is the usual setting in which dominance order is defined, as in [this MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/226537/is-there-a-short-proof-that-the-kostka-number-k-lambda-mu-is-non-zero-when) which has several proofs of your fact. If you allow $\mu$ to be just a composition rather than a partition, you need to use majorization order, which means you need to first sort the two things being compared and then use dominance order.

So, in your example of $\lambda = (4, 3, 3)$ and $\mu = (4, 2, 4)$, you really need check $4 \geq^? 4$, $4+3 \geq^? 4+\color{red}{4}$, $4+3+3 \geq^? 4+4+2$. The middle inequality fails, $\lambda$ does not dominate $\mu$.

Comment: I see. So this theorem only say for $\mu$ $\lambda$ arranged in a descending way?

Comment: @CO2 Yes, correct.